# Another word for "attack" in terms of a disease

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there another word to mean the arrival of a disease?

Comment: We often refer to an [***outbreak** of disease.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22outbreak+of+disease%22)

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to arrival in a community, the commented *outbreak* is a good choice. If you're referring to arrival in an individual, ***[onset](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onset)*** (M-W) is probably better.

Answer (score 0):

to **infect**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/infect)

> contaminate with a disease or microorganism;
>
> communicate a disease to

As in:

> The community was **infected** with a new strain of influenza.